# Looking for a good algorithm for clustering locations (lat/long) but balance the clusters by 3rd data point

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis

I have a need to analyze client data/locations and make suggestions on how to create something like a service area.  Example is I have 2500 (up 500K or more) clients with machinery that each takes a different number of hours to service each month.  I want to group the locations of the clients into service areas so that the service areas are distinct (not overlapping) and that the sum of services hours in each service area is roughly equal (~1% variance lets say).

I have tried writing versions agglomerative heirarchial, divisive heirarchial, and kmeans clustering algorithms that get me close, but it becomes very difficult to evenly balance points between clusters without the clusters overlapping.  I should also say I am doing this all in C#, although I have tried k-means-constrained (https://pypi.org/project/k-means-constrained/) but this seems to just balance on count of each location in the cluster version an additional data point such as service hours.  But, if I include the service hours in the distance calculation the clusters end up overlapping.

All methodologies I have thought of for exchanging points between clusters after performing clustering standard algorithms seems to be flawed.  I need some implementation of the Minimum Cost Flow or Hungarian method algorithms (ideally written in c#) that I can use the balance my clusters.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Is there a sample data set and some relevant source code you can provide for your current attempt?

Comment: Here is some example data.  Trying to cluster by latitude and longitude but balance service hours between clusters.  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X74I957-0yQdFCRyx7fstsk7OZQq86GD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to cluster locations based on latitude and longitude while balancing the clusters by a third data point, you can incorporate that third data point into the clustering process. Here's a general approach you can follow:

```
Preprocess the Data: Start by preprocessing your data, including the latitude, longitude, and the third data point. Ensure that the data is in a suitable format for clustering, such as numerical values or scaled features.

Define the Distance Metric: Since you are working with geographical coordinates, you need to define an appropriate distance metric to measure the similarity between locations. The Haversine distance formula is commonly used for this purpose, as it accounts for the Earth's curvature. You can compute the Haversine distance between pairs of latitude-longitude coordinates.

Combine the Data Points: To incorporate the third data point into the clustering, you can combine it with the latitude and longitude coordinates. One way to achieve this is by merging the three values into a single feature vector.

Determine the Number of Clusters: Decide on the desired number of clusters based on your problem and domain knowledge. If you don't have prior knowledge about the number of clusters, you can use techniques such as the elbow method or silhouette analysis to determine an optimal number.

Apply a Clustering Algorithm: Use a clustering algorithm that can handle multidimensional data, such as K-means, DBSCAN, or hierarchical clustering. Most clustering algorithms can accommodate additional dimensions beyond just the spatial coordinates.

Weighting the Third Data Point: Depending on the clustering algorithm you choose, you can assign weights to the dimensions or use specific algorithms that allow you to control the influence of each feature. For example, in K-means, you can assign different weights to each dimension during the optimization process.

Evaluate and Interpret the Results: Once the clustering is performed, you can evaluate the results using the appropriate evaluation metrics based on your goals. Additionally, you can analyze the characteristics of each cluster, including the distribution of the third data point within each cluster, to understand how the clusters are balanced based on that variable.
```

Remember to experiment with different clustering algorithms and parameters to find the best approach for your specific dataset and requirements.

Here's a link to get you going in the right direction.

https://github.com/ash-wicus-ml/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Longitude%20Latitude%20Coordinates.ipynb

Just add in the 3rd feature when fitting your model.

```
kmeans.fit(df[['longitude', 'latitude', 'services hours']])
```

Comment: This looks like mostly ChatGPT

Comment: This seems to be partly poorly formatted [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) output.